# can't receive JSON data from request with flask

Tags: python, json, ajax, flask

Hi have this simple code who is suppose to retreive the JSON from a request and it doesn't work properly, everytime i try to print the json in python it gives me a request object.

```
@app.route('/api/save_product', methods=['POST'])
@flask_login.login_required
def save_product():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get the fields for the db
        data = request.get_json()
        print(data["title_en"])
        return {"status": "success"}
```

this will print
`<Request 'http://localhost:5000/api/save_product' [POST]>`

Here is my Javascript

```
var data = {
        title_en: this.querySelector("#title_en").value,
        title_fr: this.querySelector("#title_fr").value,
        origin: this.querySelector("#origin").value,
        note: this.querySelector("#note").value,
        available: this.querySelector("#available").value,
        certified: this.querySelector("#certified").value,
        cost: this.querySelector("#cost").value,
        price: this.querySelector("#price").value,
        special: this.querySelector("#special").value
      };
      console.log(data);

      const self = this;
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          if (data.status == "success") {
            self.closeSection();
            //update site-order list of product so it appears
            //focus the product list on the new item
          }
        }
      };
        xhttp.open('POST', "/api/save_product", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
      xhttp.send(data);
```

Comment: Just a note, you can change the line `@app.route('/api/save_product', methods=['POST'])` to simply `@app.post('/api/save_product')` and then remove the `if` statement.